# My Custom Post is show in the Edit Category but Not Display in the Add New Category?Code below

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In the Admin Panel Custom field is Display in the Edit Category like this?
[Edit Category Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FftYH.png)
But in the admin panel custom field is Not Show in the ADD NEW CATEGORY.
[Add New Category Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcXm4.png)

```
function extra_edit_tax_fields($tag) {
$t_id = $tag->term_id;
$term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_$t_id");
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Icon Field'); ?></label></th>
    <td>

        <select style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" name="term_meta[img]" id="term_meta[img]" >

            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-user-circle') { ?> selected  <?php } ?>   value="fa-user-circle">&#xf2bd;</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-desktop') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-desktop">&#xf108;</option>

            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-indent') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-indent">&#xf03c;</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-wifi') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-wifi">&#xf1eb;</option>

            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-search') { ?> selected  <?php } ?>   value="fa-search">&#xf002;</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-ban') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-ban">&#xf05e;</option>

            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-chevron-circle-right') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-chevron-circle-right">&#xf138;</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-cloud-download') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-cloud-download">&#xf0ed;</option>

            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-cog') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-cog">&#xf013;</option>
            <option style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" <?php if (esc_attr($term_meta['img']) == 'fa-gg-circle') { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="fa-gg-circle">&#xf261;</option>

        </select>

        <p class="description"><?php _e('Select the icon '); ?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
 add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'extra_edit_tax_fields', 10, 2);


function extra_add_tax_fields($tag) {
$t_id = $tag->term_id;
$term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_$t_id");
}
add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'extra_add_tax_fields', 10, 2);
function save_extra_taxonomy_fields($term_id) {
if (isset($_POST['term_meta'])) {
$t_id = $term_id;
$term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_$t_id");
$cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['term_meta']);
foreach ($cat_keys as $key) {
if(isset($_POST['term_meta'][$key])) {
$term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
}}
update_option("taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta);
}}
add_action('edited_category', 'save_extra_taxonomy_fields', 10, 2);
```

add_action('create_category', 'save_extra_taxonomy_fields', 10, 2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the metabox also appear on the new category form you need to hook the function to the `category_add_form_fields` action as well as the edit one. Updating the code to add the 2nd line below makes the box appear in my test installation.

```
add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'extra_edit_tax_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'extra_edit_tax_fields', 10, 2);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/

Comment: Thanks Willian Patton but i am also add add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'extra_edit_tax_fields', 10, 2); on top of the function function extra_add_tax_fields($tag) { and Also try this below the function but nothing happen still not working?

Comment: Adding the code above makes the box appear in my installation on the new category form. I thought that was what the question was about. There are additional errors produced me when I used your code - about accessing properties of non-objects. Perhaps you need to also go back through and do some sanity checking to prevent any additional erroneous code from outputting in addition to the form item that you desire.

Comment: Thanks William Patton my code is now working , thanks alot Sir Willian Patton , You are Superb

Comment: Perfect, I am happy to have helped :) Also see my notes above (those errors may just be local for me due to me not having the same base setup as you, still worth looking at though). If this answers your question please mark it as the correct answer so that future searchers know that this one has a solution.

Comment: Okk Willian Patton Mark it as a correct answer :) And Again bundle of thanks

Comment: Good stuff, this will help anyone with the same question in future find solution quicker (I have answered this one a few times in the wordpress forums)

Comment: Good William Sir :)